# Why can't I favourite a question in Android?

Tags: bug, status-completed

This has been annoying me for a while and I thought it might just go away, but it hasn't so here I am bringing it to the community's attention.

When I try to click the favourite star graphic when browsing Programmers on my Android phone (currently v2.2) all I can reach is the downvote (Argh! Not what I intended at all!) or Facebook button.

Ok, this could be a fault of the Android browser since I certainly don't have a problem on any PC device, but there may be a CSS issue that is causing this.

Hope this is an appropriate question for meta, if not - well the Hammer of Close will just have to fall upon me.

Comment: I can favorite on my Android phone now; can you confirm that it works for you?

Comment: Yep. All good. Thanks for sorting it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe this issue is specific to some browsers on Android 2.2, but not 2.3.

We've reproduced this on Android 2.2, we'll see if there's some way to work around it. The Android browser is know for some strange behavior regarding "clickable" areas.

Comment: OK. Perhaps a comment later on if the bug is cleared or marked as a "Cannot fix"?

Answer (score 1):

This will be fixed in the next build. It's quite interesting: The click action on that star is bound via [jQuery.live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/) (which isn't a "real" event handler) and is very close to other "clickable" areas (namely downvote and Facebook, as you noticed yourself).

Because of this, the Android browser assumes you meant to tap one of the buttons in the star's proximity, causing the event to never bubble up to the document object (which is neccessary for a `.live()` event to work).

We gave the star (which is an `<a>` element) a *pro forma* `href` attribute, after which the Android browser is willing to consider it a clickable area.

Comment: Looking forward to seeing the fix.